# Quais justificativas/implicações para remoção do Permanent Generation?

Tags: java, java-8

Pude observar que no "Java HotSpot Performance Engine" 8 o PermGen foi removido, mas qual a motivação disso e para onde foi realocado? Existe alguma implicação nisso, por exemplo nos classloaders? 
Gostaria de uma abordagem mais aprofundada sobre o assunto.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Poste isso como uma resposta para que eu possa votar nela apropriadamente. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A remoção do Metaspace começou com a [JEP 122](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/122).

> Mas qual a motivação disso e para onde foi realocado?

Quem trabalhou com Java já deve ter tomado algum `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` durante um redeploy. Esse tipo de problema geralmente ocorre devido a `ClassLoader` leaks que rapidamente enchem a PermGen.

A PermGem foi pensada como um pequeno espaço com políticas bem conservadores de *Garbage Collection* (no início simplesmente não havia *GC* nessa área); a idéia era que definições de classes, `Strings` e variáveis estáticas estivessem em um pequeno espaço "permanente" de memória contíguo ao *heap*.

Na prática porém, em um mundo de servidores de aplicação Java EE e containers OSGi (e Servidores de aplicação Java EE rodando em containers OSGi) essas informações não são assim tão permanentes.

Outras JVMs como a [JRockit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/overview/index.html) (inicialmente desenvolvida pela [BEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEA_Systems)) não implementam o conceito de PermGen. A VM JRockit é muito utilizada no *server side*, principalmente em instalações do [WebLogic](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/overview/index.html) (parte significativa dos negócios da Oracle no mundo Java). Dessa forma, faz sentido para a Oracle convergir suas implementações em uma única VM.

Do lado do [HotSpot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) (herdado da [Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems)) a solução encontrada foi mover as informações que estavam no PermGen para uma nova área da memória nativa apelidada de Metaspace. A grande vantagem aqui é que essa área pode crescer (e diminuir), facilitando o *tuning*.

Na prática isso faz parte de um esforço maior. A Oracle está fortalecendo e unificando seu modelo comercial com o ecossistema [Oracle Java SE Advanced / Suite](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/overview/index.html). A idéia é que clientes comerciais da Oracle utilizem o melhor da stack da BEA (como o [Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html)) sem que a Oracle tenha que dar manutenção em duas VMs.

> Existe alguma implicação nisso, por exemplo nos classloaders?

O Metaspace foi desenhado levando em consideração políticas de *Garbage Collection* e *Class unloading*. Nos tempos da PermGen novas implementações de GC tinham sempre que fazer algum esforço extra para lidar com essa área (o que implica em mais *switches* para tuning como `-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` e `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`, algoritmos complicados e custosos no HotSpot e limitações na ergonomia do GC).

Na nova versão do HotSpot isso mudou. Quando o Metaspace atinge determinado tamanho (i.e., limiar de memória) a VM dispara o GC. O limiar inicial é então ajustado conforme o espaço liberado (se pouco espaço foi liberado o limiar para GC aumenta, se muito espaço foi liberado o limiar para GC diminui). Ou seja, a VM tende a encontrar um ponto de equilíbrio entre o tamanho do Metaspace e a quantidade de vezes que o GC deve entrar em ação automaticamente.

Mas e os `ClassLoader` leaks? Eles continuam acontecendo é claro, e como por padrão não existem restrições para o tamanho do Metaspace, esses leaks podem consumir toda a memória nativa / *swap* máquina. Do lado positivo, ao invés de configurar um `-XX:MaxPermSize` fixo logo de cara, você pode monitorar a sua aplicação, examinar picos de uso no Metaspace e fazer *tuning* com bem mais informações (ainda é possível limitar o Metaspace com `–XX:MaxMetaspaceSize`, bem como setar limiares para GC e coisas do gênero).

Isso também melhora a ergonomia de GC o consumo de memória para pequenos aplicativos e microservices. O tamanho padrão da PermGen era de `32MB` para VMs client e `64MB` para VMs server; na minha plataforma / VM o GC já começa a rodar quanto o Metaspace atinge *21MB*, liberando uma quantidade significativa de memória que antes ficava reservada. Por outro lado aplicativos maiores podem sofrer alguns *GCs* desnecessários até a VM ajustar o limiar, isso pode ser evitado setando o limiar inicial para um valor mais alto (com o parâmetro -`XX:MetaspaceSize`).

---

#### Referências:

1. [Where Has the Java PermGen Gone?](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-PERMGEN-Removed)
2. [Will Java 8 Solve PermGen OutOfMemoryError?](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/03/java-8-permgen-metaspace)
3. [Java 8: From PermGen to Metaspace](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.ie/2013/02/java-8-from-permgen-to-metaspace.html)
4. [About G1 Garbage Collector, Permanent Generation and Metaspace](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/about_g1_garbage_collector_permanent)
5. [Metaspace in Java 8](http://java-latte.blogspot.in/2014/03/metaspace-in-java-8.html)

Comment: ótima explanação, obrigado.